# Constructing the SQL query below

Tags: sql

GOALS (~1700 rows)

```
YEAR COUNTRY   NAME              NUM_GOALS
-------------------------------------------
2018 England   Harry Kane                6
2018 France    Antoine Griezmann         4
2014 Argentina Lionel Messi              4
2014 Brazil    Fred                      1
2010 Germany   Thomas Muller             5
2010 Japan     Shinji Okazaki            1
1992 England   Gary Linekar              6
```

CHAMPIONS (~500 rows)

```
YEAR    COUNTRY NAME    ROLE
-------------------------------------------------
2018    France  Didier Deschamps    Manager
2018    France  Hugo Lloris Goalkeeper
2018    France  Paul Pogba  Midfielder
2014    Germany Joachim Loew    Manager
2014    Germany Mesut Ozil  Midfielder
2014    Germany Miroslav Klose  Forward
2002    Brazil  Da Silva    Midfielder
1994    Brazil  Da Silva    Midfielder
1998    France  Didier Deschamps    Midfielder
```

Write a query showing all world cup winning players who have never scored a goal.

What I am unsure about is whether to use a join for this and whether there is a need to specify and ID's if a join is to be used.

I'd be grateful for extra clarification and help with this, or if my query needs any tweaking.

What I have tried:

This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT GOALS.NAME 
FROM GOALS
INNER JOIN CHAMPIONS ON CHAMPIONS.COUNTRY = GOALS.NAME
WHERE GOALS.NUM_GOALS = 0;
```

Comment: Help us help you - please share the table(s) definition(s)

Comment: Are there rows in table GOALS where column NUM_GOALS is zero?

Answer (score 1):

Problems with your query:

- the join condition does not look right
- even if it was, it searches for players that had at least one world cup without scoring a goal - which is different from those that *never* scored a goal

You could use `not exists`:

```
select c.*
from champions c
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from goals g 
    where g.country = c.country and g.name = c.name and g.num_goals > 0
)
```

This assumes that `(country, name)` tuples do identify a player.

On the other hand, if you want players that won a world cup without scoring a goal in that particular event, then you can either add a correlation condition on `year`, or use a straight join:

```
select c.*
from champions c
inner join goals g 
    on  g.country = c.country
    and g.name = c.name
    and g.year = c.year
where g.num_goals = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ON` condition is comparing `CHAMPIONS.COUNTRY = GOALS.NAME`, which is not a good comparison for joining these two tables.  I would suggest doing this:

```
SELECT 
  GOALS.NAME
FROM 
  GOALS
INNER JOIN
  CHAMPIONS 
ON
  CHAMPIONS.COUNTRY = GOALS.COUNTRY
WHERE
   GOALS.NUM_GOALS = 0;
```